# Ruby condition expression parsing order

Tags: ruby, expression, conditional-statements

Consider the following two code snippets:

The first...

```
 if var1 = 'AAA' && var2 = 'BBB'
   puts "var1: #{var1}"
   puts "var2: #{var2}"
 end
```

outputs:

> BBB BBB

The second...

```
 if var1 = 'AAA' || var2 = 'BBB' || var3 = 'CCC'
   puts "#{var1} #{var2} #{var3}"
 end
```

outputs:

> AAA

Why in the first example code is parsed by the Ruby interpreter from the right, but with the second example from the left? Where can I find how exactly Ruby is parsing operators (expression) inside of conditions (if/unless...)?

Comment: Ruby operator precedence is *exactly* what you should be reviewing here. And, please don't post your questions as puzzles. Give us the information required to answer, and then pose your question in as straightforward a manner as possible.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @sawa, what do you mean?

Comment: @ndn The OP's code does not output what OP claims to output.

Comment: @sawa, it does... what do you get when you execute it?

Comment: @ndn I get `var1: BBB
var2: BBB` (with linebreak).

Answer (score 4):

Both are parsed from left to right.

What confuses you here is that `&&` and `||` have higher precedence than `=`.

---

Therefore:

```
var1 = 'AAA' && var2 = 'BBB'
```

is equivalent to

```
var1 = ('AAA' && var2 = 'BBB')
```

which leaves you with both variables equal to `BBB`, because `AAA` is truthy.

---

Same for the second example:

```
var1 = 'AAA' || var2 = 'BBB' || var3 = 'CCC'
```

is equivalent to

```
var1 = ('AAA' || var2 = 'BBB' || var3 = 'CCC')
```

which just assigns `AAA` to `var1` and nothing more.

---

To achieve what you want here, either put the brackets where you need them or use `and` and `or` as they have lower precedence. Either way, it is not that readable to assign values while checking for condition to begin with.

Comment: "it is not that readable to assign values while checking " - rubymine even highlights this as a warning

Comment: it's worth mentioning that `&&` and `||` have higher precedence than assignment specifically so that you can use `x = a && b && c` and have it work as expected.